# How to Use Intent to pas Data through Activities in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent

I have to pass an integer through

> `startActivity(Intent(intent));`

But i dont know the correct syntax to achieve that i tried what i could but the default value dont change.

### [image]

[image]

How can i Solve the fact that my Quiz id never change??

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logs. Please post all text as text.

Comment: try change to `startActivity(intent)`

Comment: @ST i just did but nothing changed

Comment: when you get value, `var Quiz_id:Int = intent.getIntExtra("Quiz_id",0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I see, you are creating intent for the same activity instead of the one you are passing value to. It's almost fine, you just need to do this in `onItemClick` in first activity:

```kotlin
val quizIntent = Intent(this, QuizView::class.java)
intent.putExtra("QuizID", position)
startActivity(quizIntent)
```

and in `QuizView` in `onCreate()` method do:

```kotlin
val quizId = intent.getIntExtra("QuizID", -1) // -1 is default value, so -1 would mean you didn't pass position properly or at all
```

Comment: I saw that you are creating new Intent in `QuizView` activity. Don't do that. Just after `setContentView` write `val quizId = intent.getIntExtra("QuizID", -1)`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
val intent = Intent(this, QuizView::class.java)
intent.putExtra("QuizID", position)
startActivity(intent)
```

in the receiving end

```
val quizId = intent.getIntExtra("QuizID")
```

Comment: it tells me Unresolved reference: getExtra

Comment: ok you tried the same getIntExtra with my way?

Comment: you need a extra parameter when using getIntExtra

Answer (score -1):

if yow want to pass the position clicked

```
 Intent profileIntent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, DestinationActivity.class);
                profileIntent.putExtra("Quiz_id", postion);
                startActivity(profileIntent);
```

and to receive that item on DestinationActivity after on create write

```
final String Quiz_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("Quiz_id");
```

this way you'll retrieve the position clicked  and  you can use it further.

Comment: but its not a string?

Comment: Yeah but you can use it like a string and convert it to int or long whatever you want and use it later it just makes it easy to transfer info from one activity to another